# Free addon that shows closing (curly)braces for javascript

Tags: javascript, visual-studio, add-on, curly-braces, braces

I usually get confused by the braces and curly braces in javascript.
It takes me sometime to know, for example, which opening braces does this one belong to, etc.

Can anyone suggest a free(ie. not resharper!) addon that does that?

I just wish they'd implement it already in Visual Studio like it is for C# etc.

I am using VS2010.

Comment: I don't code Javascript in VS but you've tried [JScript Editor Extensions](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/872d27ee-38c7-4a97-98dc-0d8a431cc2ed/)?

Comment: Looks great :) will give it a try